# About VS Code-Server early access

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, visual-studio-code-server

I signed up this form: https://aka.ms/vscode-server-signup

Is there anybody signed up and got feedback through their gmail.
if there is can one of them tell me how manys days it took to get feedback?

i have been waiting for 1 week.

information about official vscode-server:
https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/07/07/vscode-server